# Array Privacy Java - Basic

Tags: java, arrays, privacy

I'm sorry for (another) admittedly quite basic question, but I'm having more problems in some Java code that I have to right for class. The assignment is to do a sieve of Eratosthenes program, and while my constructor seems to work (calling `myArray[50]` from the `main` method gives the value it was initialized to), it doesn't reflect any changes that the other classes were meant to make to `myArray`. Also, `print()` prints nothing (probably because the function sees an unitialized version of `myArray`.).

The goal is that SieveEm() and deleteStuff() mark all of the non-primes as false, the print() comes by and prints all of the prime numbers(marked true).

I couldn't seem to find anything on the internet/StackOverflow addressing the problem. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public class Sieve {
    private int count;
    private boolean[] myArray;
    public Sieve(int length){
        count = length+1;
        boolean[] newArray = new boolean[length+1];
        if(length>=1){
            newArray[0]=false;
            newArray[1]=false;
            if(length>=2){
                for(int i=0;i<=length;i++){
                    newArray[i]=true;
                }
            }
        }
        this.myArray = newArray;
    }
    public void SieveEm(){
        System.out.println("here now");
        System.out.println(this.myArray[50]==true);
        for(int i=0; i<count;i++){
            System.out.println("We got this far");
            if(this.myArray[i]){
                deleteStuff(i);
            }
        }
    }
    public void deleteStuff(int current){
        int increment= current;
        current+=increment;
        while(current<count){
            this.myArray[current]=false;
            current+=increment;
        }
    }
    public void print(){
        this.SieveEm();
        for(int i=2;i<count;i++){
            if(this.myArray[i]){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Sieve mySieve = new Sieve(100);
        mySieve.print();
        System.out.println(mySieve.myArray[50]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the difference between "what you expect to happen" vs "what is happening?"

Comment: Just as a side note but if SieveEm() is a method then you should start it with a lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will go method by method for anything that has issues because there seems to be a bit that needs correcting.

For `public void deleteStuff(int current),` this `int increment= current; current+=increment;` seems rather redundant and hurtful because `increment` does not do anything special. Even more importantly, your `while - loop` will never terminate because on the first pass `current = 0;` and `increment = 0;`. If you do `current++;` then your `while-loop` WILL terminate. Also, if you while loop does progress and goes through the array, all true values will be set to false.

Onto `print()`. This method does not print anything because you set the entire `myArray` to false. Of course, because of the `while-loop` issue I mentioned earlier, the `for-loop` to print is never reached because you are stuck in a never ending `while-loop.` So, if you solve the `while - loop` issue, you set every element in the array to false so the statment below never executes.

`if(this.myArray[i])
{
System.out.println(i);
}`

If I notice anything else I will let you know.

Comment: Thank you! I know that it should just be this.myArray[50], I just got paranoid and started doing extra things to be safe!

Comment: @CBlumey I hate to be a bit of a jerk, or whatever word applies, but Joe Hutchinison's first answer was totally off and completely incorrect and did not even answer your question. Three minutes after I answer your question, he edited his response and it magically contained the issue that I mentioned in my answer. You do not have to select my answer as the correct one, but I ask that you do as I provided the correct answer to your question before Joe Hutchinson, and I didnt steal anyone's answer.

Comment: @CBlumey and perhaps also downvote his answer as he didnt provide an answer he discovered himself, instead he copied my solution.

Comment: I did see his first answer, although I saw his second answer before I saw yours. I'll mark yours as the correct one, as it's more in-depth anyways. I don't want to downvote because I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @CBlumey thank you. you didnt have to change your selection, I just felt a bit miffed that my idea was claimed by another. I do appreciate your selecting mine as the correct answer, and I hope your program works out. If you have any other questions, you can send me a comment with a link to whatever your next question is. :)